# Is There a Way to Tell What Language Was Used for a Program?

Tags: windows, delphi, programming-languages, executable, reverse-engineering

I have a desktop program I downloaded and installed. It runs from an .exe file.

Is there some way from the .exe file to tell what programming language was used to write the program?

Are there any tools are available to help with this?

What languages can be determined and which ones cannot?

---

Okay here are two of the sort of things I'm looking for:

1. [Tips to Determine Whether an App is Written in Delphi or Not](http://delphi.wikia.com/wiki/Determine_Delphi_Application)
2. This ["IsDelphi" program](http://cc.embarcadero.com/Item/22159) by [Bruce McGee](https://stackoverflow.com/users/19183/bruce-mcgee) will find all applications built with Delphi, Delphi for .Net or C++ Builder that are on your hard drive.

Comment: I almost closed this as not programming-related. I may yet. Please say why you want to do this? This sounds like a request for a utility.

Comment: Why do you want to know?  If you're just curious about a specific program, ask the author, they will probably be happy to tell you.  Otherwise, there's probably a better way to solve your Real Question, instead of the Attempted Solution asked about here.

Comment: John/Roger: Actually my question just happened honestly when I saw a feature in another program that I thought would be good in mine. I'd have an easier time looking for how that feature was implemented if I knew the language it was written in.

Comment: It's a valid reason. Don't close this.

Comment: What feature?  Knowing the implementation language isn't really significantly helpful, but asking about that specific feature in combination with languages/toolkits you're already using or you already know is much more likely to elicit an answer you can use.

Comment: Roger: This particular feature had to do with exception handling and reporting. But this isn't the only time I've wanted to do this.

Comment: Just because you don't think the OP has a good reason to do what he's doing doesn't mean it's "not programming related". This seems like a perfectly reasonable question to me. The interesting (and very programming-related) part of this question is whether or not you can actually deduce this and how, not whether a tool exists.  Seriously guys, not everyone on here is an *application* developer.  There is more than one type of programming and more than one definition of "useful".

Comment: Why question the question? If he wants to know, then he wants to know, and since it involves software, it's an appropriate question for Stack Overflow. I don't know about Mr. Kessler's motivations, but I have wondered at times what language something was written in, as have many others I'm sure.

Comment: I might be a little biased, but this seems like a perfectly legitimate question to me.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

I understand your curiosity.

You can identify Delphi and C++ Builder apps and their SKU by looking for a couple of specific resources that the linker adds.  Specifically RC Data\DVCLAL and RC DATA\PACKAGEINFO.  The [XN Resource Editor](http://www.wilsonc.demon.co.uk/d10resourceeditor.htm) makes this a lot easier, but it might choke on compressed EXEs.

EXE compressors complicate things a little.  They can hide or scramble the contents of the resources.  Programs compressed with [UPX](http://upx.sourceforge.net/) are easy to identify with a [HEX editor](http://mh-nexus.de/en/hxd/) because the first 2 sections in the PE header are named UPX0 and UPX1.  You can use the app to decompress these.

Applications compiled with .Net aren't difficult to detect.  Recent versions of Delphi even include an IsAssembly function, or you could do a little spelunking in the PE header.  Check out the IsManaged function in IsDelphi.

Telling which .Net language was used is trickier.  By default, VB.Net includes a reference to Microsoft.VisualBasic, and VCL.Net apps included Borland specific references.  However, VCL.Net is defunct in favour of Delphi Prism, and you can add a reference to the VB assembly to any managed language.

I haven't looked at some of the apps that use signatures to identify the the compiler, so I don't know how well they work.

I hope this helps.

Comment: Thanks Bruce. I'm glad I added the Delphi tag to the question.

Answer (score 8):

I use [**WinDowse**](http://www.greatis.com/delphicb/windowse/) (a small freeware utility written in Delphi) to spy the windows of the program.. for example if you look at the "Class" TabSheet you can discover the "Class" Name of the control..

For example:

- TFormXX, TEditYY, TPanelZZZ for delphi apps
- WindowsForms10.XXXX.yyy,  for .NET apps
- wxWindowsXXX for wxWindows apps
- AfxWndXX for MFC/VC++ apps (I think)

I think this is the fastest way (although **not the most accurate**) to find information about apps..

Comment: Thanks Paolo, That WinDowse looks like a very useful program for this purpose. If I could give out a second accepted answer, you'd have got it.

Answer (score 4):

First, look to see what run time libraries it loads.  A C program won't normally load Visual Basic's library.

Also, examine the executable for telltale strings.  In most executables, this is near the end.  If the program uses string constants, there might be a clue in how they are stored.

Comment: Also symbols and calling convention can give it away, as well as things like how `ebp/rbp` is used with the call stack.

Answer (score 3):

A good [disassembler](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Disassembler), plus of course an excellent understanding of the underlying CPU architecture, can often help you identify the runtime libraries that are in play. Unless the exe has been carefully "stripped" of symbols and/or otherwise masked, the names of symbols seen in runtime libraries will often provide you with programming-language hints, because different languages' standards specify different names, and vendors of compilers and accompanying runtime libraries usually respect those standards pretty closely.

Of course, you won't get there without knowledge of the various possible languages and their library standards -- and if the code's author was intent to mask the information, that's not too hard for them to do, either.

Answer (score 3):

If you have available a large set of samples from known compilers, I should think this would be an excellent application for machine learning.  I believe so-called "supervised learning" is relevant here.  Unfortunately I know next to nothing about the topic—only that I have heard some impressive results presented at conferences.

You might dig through the proceedings of the *Working Conference on Reverse Engineering* to see if anyone else is interested in this problem.

Answer (score 2):

Assuming this is an application for Windows...

Does Reflector recognize it as a .NET assembly?  Then it's MSIL, 99% either VB or C#, but you'll likely never know which, nor does it matter.

Does it need an intrepreter (like Java?)?  Then it's Java (or whatever the interpreter is.)

Check what runtime DLLs it requires.

Does it require the VB runtime dlls?  Congratulations, VB from VisualStudio 6.0 or earlier.

Does it require the Delphi dlls?  Congratulations, Delphi.

Did you make it this far? C/C++.  Assume C++ unless it requires msys or cygwin dlls, in which case C has maybe a 25% chance.

Congratulations, this should come out correct for the vast majority of Windows software.  This probably doesn't actually help you though, as a lot of the same things can be done in all of these languages.

Comment: This is sort of the ruleset I was looking for. Is there anything out there that gives this in much more detail?

Comment: Well, no, and thats sort of the point.  I just rambled this off from a couple basic ideas.  If it has an external language specific requirement, such as the .NET framework, an interpreter, or language specific runtime libraries, that can clue you off.  Otherwise it can take years of experience with various compilers to be able to figure out what compiler created the code with any real accuracy.  If there are no external libraries you are best off playing the odds and calling it either C or C++ depending on the age of the binary.

Comment: How about I give you a sample written in assembly? Detecting assembly: mainly not referencing any C runtime dll and doesn't have the stdlib strings in it ("requested the runtime to terminate it in an unusual way").

Comment: If it is .Net (or Java) byte code, I would not say '... but you'll likely never know which, nor does it matter' - there are many languages which run on these platforms. Delphi Prism, VB, C# / Scala, Groovy, Clojure or AspectJ have different feature sets.

Comment: @mjustin:  I realize now I wasn't clear enough, but I did not intend this as a 100% inclusive 100% accurate walkthrough. (For instance with .NET I said 99% of the time it would be VB or C#, which is about accurate, and once it's in MSIL it doesn't matter where it came from, it'll all reverse back to C#.) My point was that a few basic rules would usually be correct for the vast majority of examples, but beyond that it could take years of experience to have an accurate idea of which language the binary was compiled from.

Answer (score 2):

IDA Pro Free (http://www.hex-rays.com/idapro/idadownfreeware.htm) may be helpful. Even if you don't understand assembly language, if you load the EXE into IDA Pro then its initial progress output might (if there are any telltale signs) include its best guess as to which compiler was used.

Answer (score 1):

Start with various options to dumpbin. The symbol names, if not carefully erased, will give you all kinds of hints as to whether it is C, C++, CLR, or something else.

Answer (score 1):

Other tools use signatures to identify the compiler used to create the executable, like PEiD, CFF Explorer and others.

They normally scan the entry point of the executable vs the signature.

**Signature Explorer** from [CFF Explorer](http://www.ntcore.com/exsuite.php) can give you an understanding of how one signature is constructed.

Answer (score 0):

It looks like the VC++ linker from V6 up [adds a signature](http://ntcore.com/files/richsign.htm) to the PE header which youcan parse.

Answer (score 0):

i suggest [PEiD](http://peid.has.it/) (freeware, closed source). Has all of Delphi for Win32 signatures, also can tell you which was packer used (if any).